# how do I fix core dump?

Tags: c, coredump

I am getting core dump by this little programm.

```
#include <dirent.h>
int main(void) {

        printf("process n%s",(long)getpid());
        exit(0);
}
```

can you explain me why?

Comment: Please check `getpid` man page, espacially its return value.

Comment: You're trying to print a `long` with the `%s` format specifier which is for printing strings. This won't end well.

Comment: The data type used for the return value of `getpid()` is `pid_t` which is an an integer type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know where your functions come from, what they're returning and how to print the return value.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("process n%ld", (long)getpid());
}
```